# Branch to project relationship

Tags: vb.net, tortoisesvn

I am relatively new to using TortoiseSVN for source control.  I am developing a system that contains many .NET project files (a solution can contain many projects).  I have one repository and the trunk contains all the projects.  What do you do if you want to make a change to a project that references another project.  Do you put both projects in the same branch? I have bought a book titled 'Subversion' but it will not arrive for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

The project files and the source control aren't coupled to one another.  Any "branch" is going to include the entire source tree, not individual "projects."  (The source control system in this case, SVN, has no knowledge of what a "project" is or how it differs from anything else.  It's just a text file in the source tree.)

You should branch at the root of the entire codebase, essentially making the branch be a fully self-sustainable version of the codebase.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for: "Any "branch" is going to include the entire source tree, not individual "projects.".

Comment: Would you put all projects used by the system in the same repository? For example, if you had two isolated projects e.g. web client and application client.  These both reference the business logic layer DLL but do not reference each other.

Comment: @w0051977: There's really no reason to separate things.  Especially if they share references.  The entire code domain should be in the repository.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you put every single project in the same repository? e.g. a sales system and a finance system that are completely independent of each other? Wouldn't they go in separate repositories?

Comment: @w0051977: Are they part of the same business domain?  Belong to the same company?  If so, absolutely.  Especially if they reference the same other projects.  It has nothing to do with whether they're "a sales system" and "a finance system" because the source control doesn't care about that context.  It depends on whether or not they're in any way related and how the code should be organized.  I can't really be specific since I don't know the context.

Comment: Thanks, I am almost ready to mark this as answered. Your answer suggests that when a branch is created, you check out all projects. Wouldn't you just checkout the relevant projects into the branch? Thanks again.

Comment: @w0051977: "Check out"?  SVN doesn't have exclusive check-outs.  What you essentially do when you create a branch is make sort of a "soft copy" of a specific revision of the codebase in the SVN database (it doesn't necessarily actually copy everything until it needs to).  Then you'd bring that copy down to your local workstation (which is in a different folder ideally, because changing workspace context in the same folder can get weird), make changes, commit them back to the server, and eventually merge back to trunk.  It's merge-based, not checkout-based.

Comment: @w0051977: The main reason why I recommend having the entire domain codebase in a single repository is to avoid conflicts of having individual repositories with projects that reference other repositories.  For example, if Project A is in one repository and has a project reference in the solution to Project B in another repository, then it can get difficult to manage if you branch one project but not another and make anything resembling a breaking change in Project B.

Comment: Can I just confirm that by "domain code base" you mean every single line of code in every single project, rather than every line of code in a problem domain (single system).

Comment: @w0051977: Correct.  Unless there's a compelling reason to keep things separate, I'd err on the side of keeping them together.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices you can make here.

You can have a separate repository for each project.   Each one has /branches, /tags, and /trunk and nothing else under the root.

You can have one repository with multiple sub-folders, one for each project.  Each sub-folder has its own /branches, /tags, and /trunk underneath.